# peewee: reusing dynamically created models

Tags: python-2.7, peewee

In my application I have a model for which I know the number of columns only at runtime. Using a function like `Factory` below to create the model solves this issue nicely. However, if I use it multiple times (with potentially varying fields), the creation of the foreign key `ref` throws an exception:

```
AttributeError: Foreign key: dynamictable.ref related name "dynamictable_set" 
collision with foreign key using same related_name.
```

The message is quite clear and when I set the `related_name` argument when creating the foreign key there is no error.

**Questions**:

1. Why can't I use the same `related_name` the second time? Do I need to redefine `StaticTable` as well?
2. Is there a better approach to write to multiple databases with dynamic models?

Minimal, reproducable example:

```
import peewee

database_proxy = peewee.Proxy()

class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database_proxy

class StaticTable(BaseModel):
    foo = peewee.DoubleField()

def Factory(fields):
    class DynamicTable(BaseModel):
        ref = peewee.ForeignKeyField(StaticTable)
    for field in fields:
        peewee.DoubleField().add_to_class(DynamicTable, field)
    return DynamicTable 

def Test(fname, fields):
    db = peewee.SqliteDatabase(fname)
    database_proxy.initialize(db)
    db.create_table(StaticTable)
    dyntable = Factory(fields)
    db.create_table(dyntable)
    db.close()


Test(':memory:', ['foo', 'bar'])
Test(':memory:', ['foo', 'bar', 'extra'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this highlights a bug in peewee where you may explicitly want to ignore any backrefs. I've opened a ticket and will resolve it.

https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/465

In the meantime, you can silence the error by setting a dynamic related_name on the model, e.g.

```
def Factory(fields):
    dynamic_name = '_'.join(fields)
    class DynamicTable(BaseModel):
        ref = peewee.ForeignKeyField(StaticTable, related_name=dynamic_name)
    for field in fields:
        peewee.DoubleField().add_to_class(DynamicTable, field)
        return DynamicTable
```

---

Update: per the fix in #465, it's now possible to disable backref validation:

```
def Factory(fields):
    class DynamicTable(BaseModel):
        ref = peewee.ForeignKeyField(StaticTable, related_name=dynamic_name)
        class Meta:
            validate_backrefs = False
    for field in fields:
        peewee.DoubleField().add_to_class(DynamicTable, field)
        return DynamicTable
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. In my question I forgot to mention, that I might have the same fields for some databases, so joining the fields to a string is not unique. I found a workaround though, I will post it in a seperate answer

Comment: For sure, I merely provided that as an example of how you might get around it.

Answer (score 1):

[@coleifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254346/coleifer)'s suggestions (in his answer) work well, as long as the list of fields is unique. As this is not guaranteed in my case, I came up with this slightly more complex solution, where all model classes are created in a factory:

```
import peewee

database_proxy = peewee.Proxy()

def orm_factory():

    class OrmWrapper:
        class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
            class Meta:
                database = database_proxy

        class StaticTable(BaseModel):
            foo = peewee.DoubleField()

        @classmethod
        def dyntable_factory(cls,fields):
            class DynamicTable(cls.BaseModel):
                ref = peewee.ForeignKeyField(cls.StaticTable)
            for field in fields:
                peewee.DoubleField().add_to_class(DynamicTable, field)
            return DynamicTable

    return OrmWrapper

def test(fname, fields):
    orm = orm_factory()
    db = peewee.SqliteDatabase(fname)
    database_proxy.initialize(db)
    db.create_table(orm.StaticTable)
    dyntable = orm.dyntable_factory(fields)
    db.create_table(dyntable)
    db.close()

test(':memory:', ['foo', 'bar'])
test(':memory:', ['foo', 'bar'])
```